# Rotating xAxis categories in Polar Chart using Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

Currently, the categories are displaying as rotation is set '0'.

[image: Default]

Where as I have to display text around the circle. something similar to this
[image: Text around the circle]

Please help me to find the right setting for this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no default option in Highcharts for this, but you can calculate the rotation for each label. Additionally, you will need to set `align` for axis labels to `center`:

```
    events: {
        render: function() {
            var ticks = this.xAxis[0].ticks,
                length = this.xAxis[0].categories.length,
                rotation = 360 / length / 2;

            Highcharts.objectEach(ticks, function(tick) {
                tick.label.attr({
                    rotation: rotation
                });

                rotation += 360 / length;
            });
        }
    }
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/shgj8o9t/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.align